# iOS 10 UITabbar selecting other tab shows it's title in index 0

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I show 5 tabs using UITabbar. How ever the first tab title keeps changing when i press a button. For example let the tabbar name be "first", alpha, beta, gamma. 
I select the "first" tabbar and click a button in the screen which keep changing title names to "second", "third", and so on. 
My problem is when the app starts the title text shows 2 same names. One is selected color blue and other is deselected color gray. When I select the tabs alpha, beta, gamma those titles also applies in "first". So the text are clustered in first tabbar. This works fine in iOS 9. From iOS 10 I get this title problem. The tabbar image are working fine its not duplicated.

```
FirstViewCtrl* tripVc = [ FirstViewCtrl new ];
UINavigationController* firstNavCtrl = [ [ UINavigationController alloc ] initWithRootViewController:firstVc ];


UITabBarController* tabBarController = [ UITabBarController new ];
[ tabBarController.tabBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlack ];
tabBarController.viewControllers = @[firstNavCtrl, alphaNavCtrl, betaNavCtrl, gammaNavCtrl];

tripVc.tabBarItem = [ [ UITabBarItem alloc ] initWithTitle:@"First" image:[ UIImage imageNamed:@"firstIcon"] selectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"firstIcon_mo"] ];

[ self.view addSubview:tabBarController.view ];
```

I fixed this by different method. I am not sure this is correct or why its happening. Instead of setting

```
[ self setTitle:@"First" ];
```

I set it as

```
[ self.navigationItem setTitle:@"First" ];
[ self.tabBarItem setTitle:@"First" ];
```

By this way if i want to change title the text are not overlapped. 
Anyone with any idea why is this happening from iOS 10

Answer (score 0):

You need to set title of for all ViewController.
such as below

```
FirstViewCtrl* tripVc = [ FirstViewCtrl new ];
tripVC.title = @"First";

alphaNavCtrl* tripVc = [ alphaNavCtrl new ];
alphaNavCtrl.title = @"alpha";
```

Comment: Even if i set the title for all viewcontrollers i still get the other tabbar title name in my 0th tabbar index. To be clear i get the word "alpha" overwritten on the word "first". Same when i click beta its overwritten first index. When i click all 4 tabs i have all the title name overwritten on first index.

Comment: No. It's working perfectly in iOS 9 but the bugs starts from iOS10. If you check this question he gets more images also. For me i get multiple text in index 0 of TabBarcontroller.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38776978/ios-10-uitabbar-more-items-visible-after-setting-title